# Ejecutar comando Replace en VisualBasics para reemplazar una formula

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

Estoy intentando crear una macro y tengo problemas al intentar usar el comando `Replace` cuando afecta a una formula en VisualBasics.

Mi situación es la siguiente:

1. En la columna L tengo calculos de pendiente de disitntos rangos: `=PENDIENTE(G33:G60;C33:C60)` `=PENDIENTE(G95:G122;C95:C122)` etc.
2. Tengo que canviar el calculo de PENDIENTE por PROMEDIO (el excel esta en castellano asi que las operaciones las tiene en castellano) de modo que quede: `=PROMEDIO(G33:G60)` `=PROMEDIO(G95:G122)` etc.

Despues de algunos intentos me he quedado aquí (tampoco se si esta bien):

```
Dim Cadena1 As String
    Cadena1 = Replace("=PENDIENTE(G*:G*;C*:C*)", "PENDIENTE", "PROMEDIO")


Dim Cadena2 As String
    Cadena2 = Replace("=PROMEDIO(G*:G*;C*:C*)", ";C*:C*", " ")


Dim iRow, StartRow As Integer
Dim Col1, ColValues As String
    Col1 = "L"
    ColValues = "M"
    StartRaw = 2

NumRows = Range(Col1 & StartRow, Range(Col1 & StartRow).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

[image: me sale este menaje y me señala la ultima fila "NumRows"]

¿Algún consejo?
Si alguien conoce algun manual de VisualBasics que pudiera ayudar o algo similar tambien lo agradecieria

Comment: Hola Albert, bienvenido. Deberias mostrar el codigo de ese intento que dices y los mensajes que te muestra para poder indicarte en que falla y donde mejorar. Recuerda leer el [Tour] y [ask] para saber cómo funciona este sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Perdon, soy nuevo aquí. Y en general en todo el mundo de la programación, estoy intentando aprender :). gracias por la correccion. Espero que la nueva edicion sea mejor. Gracias

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es reemplazar fórmulas de excel?

Comment: Si, lo quiero para reepmplazar una formula en excel, esta formula se repite muchas vececs en una sola columna, con rangos distintos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la propiedad `.formula` puedes asignarle la formula al rango de celdas.

Puse `average` en vez de `promedio` y `slope` en vez de `pendiente` porque en VBA usa los nombres en inglés

```
Sub prueba()

    Dim cell As Range

    Dim celda_inicio As String
    Dim celda_fin As String

    celda_inicio = "A7"
    celda_fin = "A15"

    Dim formula_vieja As String

    Dim posicion As Integer


    For Each cell In Range(celda_inicio, celda_fin)

        formula_vieja = cell.formula

        formula_vieja = Replace(formula_vieja, "SLOPE", "AVERAGE")

        posicion = InStr(1, formula_vieja, ",")

        If posicion > 0 Then
            cell.formula = Left(formula_vieja, posicion - 1) + ")"
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

**Funcionamiento:**

Va celda por celda en el rango especificado con las variables, y coge la formula actual y cambia `slope` por `average`

Luego busca donde está la coma . La formula en ingles no es `=PENDIENTE(G33:G60;C33:C60)` si no `=PENDIENTE(G33:G60,C33:C60)`

Si encuentra la coma, coge el cacho del `string` de la izquierda y luego añado un `")"` para cerrar la formula

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPU6G.png
           https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Nu5.png

Comment: @AlbertG voy a mirarlo luego y te digo. (borra los mensajes obsoletos para que no *molesten*  tantos ahi ^^ )

Comment: bueno lo he intentado otra vez y parece que si que da resultado, sin errores. gracias por todo

Comment: @AlbertG perdona por no contestar, estuve liado. me alegra haber sido de ayuda. considera aceptar la respuesta. Un saludo